# Amazon aws instance Ram capacity

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, storage, ram

I am using amazon aws cloud instance and its running my java application through tomcat. It receives 500 images per day and stores.
Can anybody please suggest me which instance I should choose between t2.micro, t2.small, t2.medium, etc.
What are the ram sizes available and for 500 images per day which instance I should go with.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you try them and see which works for you.  How much memory you use depends on your application and the size of the images.  If you don't know this no one does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think t2.micro server is okay to handle traffics for 500 images per day. You can monitor ram usage by using 'htop' command on ssh connection (putty). If it uses a lot of ram, you can always change instance type to next level.